# How can set default value for abstract function returned value in java

Tags: android, abstract-class

i have an abstract class and an abstract function in it like this:

```
public abstract class VolleyItem {

public enum ResponseType {Object,Array,Boolean,String,Integer }

    public abstract String setUrl();
    public abstract ResponseType setResponseType();

}
```

now i want extend a class from above class. i want when implement @Override methods, default value of them be like this:

```
public class test extends VolleyItem {

public int b = 0;
public String str = null;


@Override
public String setUrl() {
    return "my special text";
}

@Override
public ResponseType setResponseType() {
    return ResponseType.Object;
}
```

}

what should i do?
thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to make a library and when anyone extends from my class, by default i set some default values for him.

Comment: If I understood your question... the answer is no.. you can not do that.

Comment: so you already did in above class,when some one extend VolleyItem class , 2 method will be override and you already return default value in both method.all you did is everything fine.

Comment: That's against the entire point of an abstract function.  If you want it to return a default value, remove the abstract and have it return that default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking to make an abstract class with two methods

```
public abstract class VolleyItem {

public enum ResponseType {Object,Array,Boolean,String,Integer }

public abstract String setUrl();
public abstract ResponseType setResponseType();

}
```

and then you want to make a class that extend this class like:

```
public class test extends VolleyItem {

public int b = 0;
public String str = null;


@Override
public String setUrl() {
return "my special text";
}

@Override
public ResponseType setResponseType() {
return ResponseType.Object;
}
}
```

Then it is fine

but like in comments you said that you want to set a default value if anyone extends your `VolleyItem` class then it is not posssible because it is a abstract class and we have to implement  its method everytime we want to extend it.If you still want it then use a simple class without abstract keyword and then extend it.